# How can I get the list of updated folders in a git commit?

Tags: git

I am trying find a way to get only the list of folders which got updated in the last commit. I tried to use `git status --porcelain` but it gives the list of files which got updated.

```
?? folder1/test.txt
?? folder3/test2.txt
```

I can definitely extract the folder name from above result but I was wondering if there is a ready made solution for this. What I am looking for is just

```
folder1
folder2
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440420/git-diff-only-show-which-directories-changed. A good answer to get just the folder names is provided at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50440552/470818

Answer (score 2):

You can use `--dirstat` to show the changes a commit introduces within directories. Using `git show --dirstat` will display directory stats for the current commit. You can `git show --dirstat <commitish>` to show a dirstat for a specific commit, or `git diff --dirstat` to show the changes an arbitrary diff introduces.

See the [git-diff man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) for specifics.

Comment: this display last few commits as well