# git diff - only show which directories changed

Tags: git

Is there a way to list only the directories that were changed?

If I'm at the git root say, `~/project`

Files I changed are

`~/project/subtool/file1`

`~/project/subtool/file2`

`~/project/subtool3/file1`

I just want

`~/project/subtool`

`~/project/subtool3`

Answer (score 38):

You could use [`git-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) with the [`--dirstat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---dirstatltparam1param282308203gt) parameter.

In your scenario, let's say you have the following commit:

```
$ git diff --name-status HEAD~1
M       subtool/file1
M       subtool/file2
M       subtool3/file1
```

It would produce the following output:

```
$ git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD~1
  66.6% subtool/
  33.3% subtool3/
```

Make sure to add `,0`, otherwise `git diff` will by default only show directories with at least 3% changes. I also chose `files` as this is the computationally cheapest option and you do not seem to care about specific changes anyway.

If you are able to use [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) you can get rid of the percentage values (you may want to [tweak the regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions-Overview) a bit to fit your needs):

```
$ git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD~1 | sed 's/^[ 0-9.]\+% //g'
subtool/
subtool3/
```

Comment: This is pretty perfect! Is there anyway to avoid outputting the % details though? I wanna read the directories into a script and use that for something:wq

Comment: If you're scripting it, `git diff-tree` is built for that.  `doit() { git diff-tree "$@" | awk '$1$2~/04/' | cut -f2-; }`

Comment: The sed regular expression didn't work for me on macOS. BSD sed with man dated May 10, 2005.

Comment: On macOS in zsh shell I had to add the `-E` flag to the `sed` command and remove the forward slash from `\+`. This is what I used: `sed -E 's/^[ 0-9.]+% //g'`

Comment: By piping the output to another `sed` command, you can remove all the sub-folder names so you only have the top-level folders. `git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD~1 | sed -E 's/^[ 0-9.]+% //g' | sed -E 's/\/.*$//g'`

Comment: By piping Doug's last command to `uniq`, you can also remove the duplicate names.

Comment: @DougAyers How do I read your solution into an array, please?

Comment: @bluelabel you wrap the command in parenthesis, bash will parse the space delimited result into an array of branch names

Example: `my_array=($(git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD~1 | sed -E 's/^[ 0-9.]+% //g' | sed -E 's/\/.*$//g' | uniq))`

Comment: Great answer. Also note that `--dir-stat` works with `git log` too.

Answer (score 10):

this solution works also for files in the root directory:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~1 | awk -F "/*[^/]*/*$" '{ print ($1 == "" ? "." : $1); }' | sort | uniq
```

Changes in root directory will be listed as `.`

The limitation of `git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD~1` is that it doesn't show changes in the root directory.

Comment: this producing somewhat duplicates. If I have dir/foo/file-a it shows dir and dir/foo

Comment: @TheFool I added my answer in here by doing an update to Lari Hotari 's answer
You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72781954/11784338

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative using `xargs` and `dirname` instead of anything like `sed` or `awk`.

```
git diff HEAD~1 --name-only | xargs dirname | sort | uniq
```

1. `git diff …` will list modified file paths.
2. `| xargs dirname` will convert file paths into dir paths.
3. `| sort | uniq` will remove duplicates.

Note that this will produce a `.` line if you modified any files in your repo root directory.

Answer (score 0):

After adding split and uniq option from @Lari Hotari answer. One can get unique directories that are modified.

```
$(git diff --name-only HEAD~1 | awk -F "/*[^/]*/*$" '{ print ($1 == "" ? "." : $1); }' | cut -d "/" -f 1 | sort | uniq)
```

What this command does?

- First it finds all the modified files and return the parent directory of the changed files @Lari Hotari [answer][1]
- The next part is where it splits using '/' and return first element in string array i.e., Root directory of the changed file.

This command will monitor all the changes of sub-projects in monorepo and can install dependencies only for the changed workspaces using `npm i -ws` command

Comment: For that, you don't even need awk: `git diff --name-only | cut -d/ -f1 | uniq` gives you also the root dir of changed modules.

Comment: Yes, But in my mind I wanted only root directories not files so added this step after awk. As I was working on installing specific workspaces thing right now

Comment: yes, as I said, you get only directories with that command. The cut is doing that. Not awk. You can drop the awk part completely.

Answer (score -2):

Use git diff with parameter --dirstat, e.g.

```
git diff --dirstat HEAD~100..HEAD
```