# Is there a way to get the root directory path of file when running git diff against master?

Tags: git, git-diff

I am trying to get the path of the root folders of the files which were changed in a commit when running diff with `master`.
Say, I am on a branch `feature/DeploymentReady`. When running `diff` against `master`, I am trying to get the path of the parent folder rather than the path of the file inside the folder.

I have a folder structure like:

> ParentFolder
>
> - Folder1
>
>   - ChildFolder1
>
>     - Text1.txt
>     - Text2.txt
> - Folder2
>
>   - ChildFolder2
>
>     - Text3.txt
>     - Text4.txt

So, if I change something in `Text1.txt`, I want the path of `Folder1`, but I am getting the path of `ChildFolder1`.

I tried this:
`git diff --name-only HEAD^`

This gives the path to all the **files** which were changed on `feature/DeploymentReady` branch.

I also tried `git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD~1 | sed 's/^[ 0-9.]\+% //g'` with reference to an answer here [a link] [git diff - only show which directories changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440420/git-diff-only-show-which-directories-changed)

The above solution serves half the purpose. It gives me the parent folder of the file which changed, but I need the root folder path.

I am expecting to get the root folder path, but getting the parent folder path.

Answer (score 0):

How would this differ from appending the filename?

If you can return `project/folder1/childfolder1/` you would just add the filename to the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Coffey Maybe I was not clear with the question. I am getting `project/folder1/childfolder1/` but I want `project/folder1/`. As a workaround, for now, I am using `| cut -d'/' -f1-6` to move up a directory. The range `f1-6` is applicable to my actual folder structure.

Comment: @praveen I can't think of a better way to do it. I think your method of cutting works well

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, for now, I am using `git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD~1 | sed 's/^[ 0-9.]\+% //g'| cut -d'/' -f1-6` to move up a directory. The range f1-6 is applicable to my actual folder structure.