# Deploying Microservices by triggering a Jenkins pipeline whenever a change is made in a mono repository consisting of various microservices

Tags: shell, jenkins, microservices, monorepo

I have a single repository consisting of various microservices written in node js, I am trying to deploy by triggering a Jenkins pipeline for those microservices where a change is done and trying to maintain only one Jenkins file for the repository. Can this be done? I have been exploring for quite a while now, and I didn't find any useful resources. Any leads to solving this problem statement would be of great help!

Could you suggest any other famous open source CI/CD tools to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you have all the core Jenkins setup done and don't need help with git hooks or integrations to Github, but feel free to clarify if I'm mistaken. I believe you're specifically asking about how to build/deploy individual microservices housed within a mono-repo.

---

I personally don't like mono-repos for microservices for reasons like this, and prefer to share common libraries via package managers (now commonly built into version control systems like Github and Gitlab), but if you're dead-set on trying to perform individual builds and releases from a mono-repo then you'll need a script that helps you determine which folders contain changes so you can trigger their respective build pipelines. A simple one that leverages git to evaluate the most recent diff is as follows:

```sh
$ git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD~1 | sed -E 's/^[ 0-9.]+% //g' | sed -E 's/\/.*$//g'
```

*source: [git diff - only show which directories changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440420/git-diff-only-show-which-directories-changed)*

The above will parse the most recent change in the mono-repo and list out the top-level directories containing changes. You'll then be able to iterate through each and run a build pipeline specific to each folder. If each contains a Dockerfile, this may be as simple `docker build -f $FOLDER/Dockerfile`, but you could also elect to force each folder to contain a custom build script and execute in the same iterator (e.g. `$FOLDER/bin/build.sh`).

Comment: Can we build an individual pipeline for every microservice, whenever a change is done to the microservice?

Comment: Most CI systems only let pipelines be triggered based git changes at the branch or tag level, not based on changes in specific folders. You can certainly include custom pipeline logic in each service folder in your mono repo, but you’ll need some custom pre-flight step to catch the git triggers and determine which folders have changes. Thus the need for a script like the one above.

Comment: I tried by giving a tag and it did not work for me, I also tried using when conditional statement in Jenkins pipeline script, it always skips the when conditional statement :(

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can achieve what you need using Gitlab. We have pretty much the same use case, multiple Lambda functions in the same repo. The idea is not to redeploy everything each time a function is updated. This is a good starting point: https://aarongorka.com/blog/gitlab-monorepo-pipelines/