# How to get a list of new directories in a git diff?

Tags: git

I'm trying to get a list of only new directories using `git diff` (or something else).

I can get a [list of new files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203), or show [only directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50440552), but a file can be added to a directory that already exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Git doesn't store directories by themselves.  It only stores files and the paths to those files.  Thus, git doesn't know what directories are new.  It only knows it has files in directories that didn't exist before.

Comment: What happened when you tried to combine the two options you have linked?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it will output a list of directories containing new files (but the directories themselves may already exist)

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

`git ls-tree` provides part the information you need, but you'll need to use a regular `diff` to extract the actual diff.

### The general idea

This is not a fully satisfying answer, but you can use `git ls-tree` to show the contents of a commit, and with the right options reduce that to just the list of directories that commit includes.

Here's the logic behind my solution:

- `git ls-tree -r -t <commit>` outputs lines with `blob` for each file, and `tree` for each directory.
- filter that list with `grep " tree "` to see just the trees, i.e., the directories.
- Use sed to remove all but the directory name
- Run this twice and use diff to compare the two directory lists.

### Concrete solution

So, to see the list of directories in a commit:

```
git ls-tree -r -t <commit> | grep ' tree ' | sed 's/.*\t//'
```

And now diff the output of that command for the two commits. This bash command line will work interactively, but it's ugly:

```
diff <(git ls-tree -r -t  <commit1> | grep " tree " | sed 's/.*\t//') <(git ls-tree -r -t <commit2> | grep " tree " | sed 's/.*\t//')
```

To make this solution usable, I would turn it into a script. Let's call it `git-new-dirs`:

```
#!/bin/bash

commit1=$1
commit2=$2

diff <(git ls-tree -r -t "$commit1" | grep " tree " | sed 's/.*\t//') <(git ls-tree -r -t "$commit2" | grep " tree " | sed 's/.*\t//')
```

If you put that script somewhere on your PATH, you will then be able to use it by typing

```
git new-dirs <commit1> <commit2>
```