# git - show only the projects (csproj) whose files have changes

Tags: c#, .net, bash, git

This question is similar to [git diff - only show which directories changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50440420/3013479).

Let's say I have the following project structure:

```
src
  - project.sln
  - Project1
    - Foo.cs
    - Bar.cs
    - Project1.csproj
  - Project2
    - Fizz.cs
    - Buzz.cs
    - Project2.csproj
  - Project3
    - HelloWorld.cs
    - Project3.csproj
```

Now, let's say that I update `Foo.cs`, `Bar.cs` and `Fizz.cs`. This means that `src/Project1` and `src/Project2` have changes in them.

In this case, I would like to be able to ask git to return the paths of `src/Project1/Project1.csproj` and `src/Project2/Project2.csproj`.

I suppose it would also be good to only get the root dir of each project (`src/Project1/` and `src/Project2`).

How can I accomplish this with git and bash?

---

For those that feel like this is an [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info/), you are correct. The problem I am having is that `dotnet format` (which formats your .NET code) needs to analyze the entire solution, just to format 2 files (for example).

By knowing the exact projects that change, I could instruct `dotnet format` to only format those project instead, hopefully improving performance.

Comment: `dotnet format` has an `--include` option to specify the files or folders that should be formatted. Did you consider this already? With this you could always run it against the whole solution but only include the modified & added files from `git status`.

Comment: That is exactly what I do right now. But if you were to look at the logs from dotnet format, you'd see that it will still build and analyze projects unrelated to your changed files because it needs to build to run analyzers to format code. This results in my format taking +1 minute.. i want to work around this by only calling format on the specific projects that were changed to save some time.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a few readings to figure out what you were really asking, but I think I finally have it now:

- We want to find added all or modified files (deleted files are probably irrelevant? type-change, from or to symbolic link, probably can't happen, etc).
- But, we want to toss out, from this list, any files that don't exist in a directory that itself *contains or lives underneath* a directory that contains a `*.csproj` file.

That is, if the diff listing said that `README.cs` were updated in the top level, that would be irrelevant unless there were a top-level `*.csproj` file.

Now, we know that in general, the tool that will tell us which files are *changed* between any two individual commits is `git diff` (or for scripting purposes, `git diff-tree`).  For instance, `git diff parent child` will tell us about the various files that are changed.  Using `--name-status` gets us the path names and status letters.

Adding a diff *filter* for `A` and `M`, and making sure we control rename detection so that we either don't get `R` at all, or only get it for 100% matches, allows us to drop the "status" part, i.e, just `--name-only`.  If we need to handle weird characters in file names, we can add `-z` and use `\0` terminators with bash's `read -r -d $'\0'` construct (or `-d ''`; I like to write the explicit zero) as well.

Now, there's a general problem here: just because some `*.cs` file has changed doesn't mean the corresponding `*.csproj` file has also changed (well, presumably it doesn't).  So we can't inspect the *diff* output for `.csproj` files.  Unfortunately, to see whether there's a `*.csproj` file, the only *direct* tool we have here is `git ls-tree -r --full-tree child`, and it does not accept pathspec arguments, so we cannot ask about `**/*.csproj` for instance.

But there's a useful trick: *valid* `*.csproj` files are presumably always non-empty.  Using `git grep -l` with the matching expression `.` will let us find such files.  We can supply a commit hash ID here and then strip it from the output:

```
git grep -l --full-name . $hash -- "**/*.csproj" | sed "s/$hash://"
```

for instance.

Note that `git grep` is porcelain, like `git diff`, but it seems that `-l` defeats most of the options we'd have to worry about, and we want `--full-name` anyway here.  To use `git diff-tree`, just add `-r --no-commit-id`.  Rename detection is off in `git diff-tree` unless explicitly enabled.

That is, given the start and end commit hash IDs, or just `HEAD`:

```
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=AM HEAD -- "**/*.cs"
```

(If you use `HEAD` with `git grep -l` you'll want to strip a literal `HEAD:` from the output.)

Turning all this into a useful bash script will need a bit more work: you must run the `git diff-tree`, read its output, pick out the various directories, and compare with the `git grep` output's list of `*.csproj`-containing directories.